# Cluster Autoscaler on Baremetal kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

Is it possible to attach Cluster Autoscaler (CA) on baremetal kubernetes cluster?
(want to scale in/out via AWS EC2)

I did checked
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/1060
document but I couldn't find the answer I wanted.

logically, it seems possible but I am not sure I can use this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit complicated for the simple reason that your typical cloud based k8s instances are virtual machines which are managed through a simple API. This allows k8s to easily integrate with cloud providers and manage autoscaling simply by issuing API calls to your provider.

With a bare metal setup it is tricky, since you need a way to be able to communicate with your bare metal nodes that is k8s native. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/953#issuecomment-396583127) is a complicated version of what your solution will look like.

Alternatively, what you can do is use the `metal3` project. You will supply `--cloud-provider cluster-api` to your autoscaler( see [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/clusterapi) doc). You will then run `cluster-api-provider-m3` in your cluster, along with `baremetal-operator`. This will allow you to manage your bare metal instances as k8s objects, which are manipulated using the cluster-api provider, which is what your autoscaler will engage with.

Here's some information on [metal3](https://metal3.io/) project. [Here](https://metal3.io/try-it.html) is a guide on how to get started with `metal3`.

If you plan to use an Amazon service like EKS and want to scale based on your on-premise k8s nodes, you will need a specialized EKS offering like `EKS Anywhere` which is very expensive.

Comment: From previous question, you did introduced me about metal3. Airship solutions was more complicated, but I should study deeper about metal3. thanks for your help. have a nice day

Comment: I did looked about EKS Anywhere and Distro but I couldn't find more infos about scaling on single cluster.That is why I dind't mentioned about AWS services. AWS outpost was the only architecture that autoscale. But I didn't choosed this because, controlplane should be on AWS

Comment: I see. All the best with your work :)